# Is calling my webapi from itself as an easy way to reliably run a background task a bad idea?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a .net webapi project that sometimes wants to return fast to the caller and then immediately do some things that take a bit longer, like sending an email. I know this would be best done using a [Worker Role, proper scheduler, etc](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx), and in the longer term I'll do that. But in the shorter term it has been proposed that I use WebClient to call myself. This feels like a bad idea to me but I can't think of good enough reasons why. I'm currently using .net 4.5.1 so can't use [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx) although that seems like the best easy solution. In this scenario I'm happy to accept the risk that if the call fails the original caller won't be notified, e.g. if the email can't be sent.

Some thoughts on why this is/isn't a bad idea:

- it'll put undue load on resources by routing through IIS as a separate request ... but in this case the performance impact would be negligible (i.e. we have not much load) so that's not such a problem.
- in a load-balanced scenario it might not go to the same webserver, which feels wrong. But that doesn't seem like it'll cause any problems.
- it needs to pass an authentication token, but it's pretty trivial to ensure that works fine.
- if I do fire a new webapi call then my elmah logging will track any problems nicely.

Is this a totally bad practice, in which case why, or is this a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: I don't get how you would accomplish this. The WebClient is going to fire and forget the request? Just seems like a terrible idea. Why not explore your other options for running the code [in the background](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)?

Comment: The how is pretty easy - create a `WebClient`, call a GET on the appropriate URL. Explaining _why_ this is a bad idea is harder. I feel it's a bad idea, but why? Using an option like QueueBackgroundWorkItem is also fire and forget. I'm not looking for alternatives, just a good answer for why this isn't a good idea.

Comment: Show your code. How you do this is highly relevant.